# Inequality of small two numbers with power

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $0<x,y<1$ are two real numbers and $n\in\mathbb N$. Is the following inequality true $$x^n-y^n\leq x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}?$$

I split into two cases:

Case1: when $y<x$.

Case2:when $x<y.$

But in both the cases, I can't conclude anything.

Comment: It's enough to assume that $x \geq y$, say.  Have you considered some values of $x$ and $y$ to test if it's true?  In what context did this question arise?  What tools are available for use here?

Comment: I estimate some integration and on this, I face this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If its true for all $x,y$ with $0<x,y<1$, then it must also be true for all $x,y$ with $0 \leq x, y \leq 1$, since both $x^n-y^n$ and $x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}$ are continuous functions.

What happens if you let $y=0?$

Comment: foy y=0 and y=1 it's not true as $x<1$

Comment: Exactly, so if you prove the assertion that it also must hold for $x,y$ with $0 \leq x,y \leq 1$ then you are done.

Comment: Can you tell more?

Comment: I claim that if $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are continuous functions and you a sequences $(x_n,y_n)$ which converges to $(x,y)$ and $f(x_n,y_n) \leq g(x_n, y_n)$ for all $n$ then you must have $f(x,y) \leq g(x,y)$. If not then $f(x,y)-g(x,y)> \epsilon >0$ for some $\epsilon$. You should be able to use that and the continuity of $f$ and $g$ (hence the fact that $f(x_n, y_n) $ converges to $f(x,y)$ and likewise for $g$) to get a contradiction.